# For-each loop execution in logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

[image: this is what iam trying to do]i have added two actions inside for-each loop. i need to execute it like when one entity is inserted the next action replace entity should be done.

But it's not working like that all are getting inserted and replace action is taking place. any answer how to achieve this.[image]

Comment: What do you mean `replace action is taking place`, please provide more information about what you want.

Comment: @george u provided me a solution right for row key increment. so i implemented that in an for each. iam getting an entity from a table and replacing that entity to change the row key value.but i can't able to achieve it an for loop.

Comment: So in your  flow insert entity is to add new entities. And in the replace actions, your are using dynamic values or what,and what means can't able to achieve it, you got an error or the value is not what you want?

Comment: i can't able to to achieve the value i want. in that array three values are there for each row key i need to get is as for first array value the row key should be 1 and for second 2 and for third 3. but iam getting the row key for first value as 1 and second value as 1 and third value 1. in replace entity iam incrementing the table value. for partition key i am using guid() function

Comment: Any process, is this what you want?

Comment: i want to replace the entity which iam inserting in for-each loop. if i use get entities it will get all the entity.

Comment: You could only replace the entity json except the RowKey or PartitionKey. In my answer I have said for now if you want to replace the whole entity including the RowKey or PartitionKey, you have to delete it and insert one entity you want.

Comment: i need only the row key to be changed. not other values.in a for-loop iam not able to take the single entity or specify the single entity

Comment: I know you just want to change row key however this is not supported.  And what mean `iam not able to take the single entity or specify the single entity`?

Comment: u said to delete the entity and replace it. after parse json iam running for-each loop and inserting entity. in that for-loop i tried to add deletion aciton and replace action. when i do that iam not able to select particular entity which was inserted in for-each loop

Comment: I have update the answer, check it.

Answer (score 0):

For now azure table doesn't support update the RowKey or PartitionKey, What you would need to do is perform 2 operations: first delete the entity with existing PartitionKey/RowKey and then insert new entity with new PartitionKey/RowKey.

Please refer to the below action.

[image]

**Update**: suppose you don't know how to update the entity only change the rowkey without other value changed. Add a compose action to store the original entity, then delete the entity and insert an entity with the original with a new rowkey.

[image]

Hope this could hep you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.